# What is the GET function on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, events

Are Get functions read-only? like if a  GetObject, GetBucketPolicy or GetBucketLogging event is executed on an s3 then does that mean the user only read the information

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is a standard practice. While building any REST API;  ( just like when we create beans and implement getter and setter methods ) get api are for "select" while set api are for update/delete.. Similarly you have PutObject also to update an object onto S3